# Appending list in python results in multiple of the same entry

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, pysimplegui

I'm creating a program to roll a series of 'dice' for use in a tabletop, with a simple pysimplegui to display the results so i can ship it to a friend as an exe.

The expected result is it would display 'hit pool 1: x y z' 'hit pool 2' x y z

however i am receiving the following:
`[['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #1', 29, 87, 34, 55, 33, 77, 36, 90, 57, 93], ['Hit Pool #2', 4, 70, 28, 12], ['Hit Pool #2', 4, 70, 28, 12], ['Hit Pool #2', 4, 70, 28, 12], ['Hit Pool #2', 4, 70, 28, 12], ['Hit Pool #3', 53, 39, 12], ['Hit Pool #3', 53, 39, 12], ['Hit Pool #3', 53, 39, 12], ['Hit Pool #4', 81, 32, 72], ['Hit Pool #4', 81, 32, 72], ['Hit Pool #4', 81, 32, 72]]`

i've considered adding more code to simply delete duplicates but id rather fix the problem than bandaid together a solution.

my current code is as follows

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
Count = 0;
TotalDice = 10;
HitCount = 0;
TotalRolls = [];


LPanel = [[sg.Button("RollNP", key="RollNP")]]
RPanel = [[sg.Text("", enable_events=True, key="GuiTextCount")], [sg.Multiline("", enable_events=True, key="GuiDiceOut")]]
layout = [sg.Column(LPanel), sg.VSep(), sg.Column(RPanel)],
window = sg.Window("Noble Phantasm Roller", layout, size=(1280, 720))


def NPRoll():
    global TotalDice;
    global Count;
    global TextCount;
    
    Count +=1
    TextCount = str(Count);
    Header = "Hit Pool #" + str(Count);
    print(Header);
    Rolls = [];
    Rolls.append(Header);
    for x in range(TotalDice):
        y = random.randint(1, 100)
        ##Rolls.append('');
        ##Rolls[Count]=(y);
        Rolls.append(y);
        #print(y)
        if y >= 55:
            TotalDice -=1;

        if TotalDice == 0:
            #TotalRolls.append(Rolls);
            #print(TotalRolls);
            window["GuiTextCount"].update("Hit " + TextCount + " Times!")
            DisplayDice()
            Count = 0;
            break
        TotalRolls.append(Rolls);
                
    
    if TotalDice > 0:
                NPRoll()
##end nproll

def DisplayDice():
    print('fired')
    window["GuiDiceOut"].update(TotalRolls)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == "RollNP":
        TotalDice = 10;
        NPRoll()
```

Comment: `TotalRolls.append(Rolls)` shouldn't be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: thank you, that did the trick! I guess i went code blind after staring at it for too many hours.